# Is there a way i can remove image dimensions from a wordpress image link

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Am inserting post thumbnails on wordpress posts but they appear to be blurry because of the extra dimensions added to the image link.

`/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/vantag-3-150x150.jpg`

How can i get rid of the `150x150` dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that and fix your size by applying this code into your functios.php file inside theme

```
function wpdocs_setup_theme() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); // you can change the value form here
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_setup_theme' );
```

Comment: this function changes the appearance of the featured image in a single post however, the thumbnails on the archive page / loop are still blurry and still have the image dimensions ```150x150``` that i would like to eliminate from the image link.

Comment: I finally found a solution to my problem, it was a problem with regex function in the functions.php file, I fixed it by replacing my original regex from ```$html = preg_replace('/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html);```  to  ```$html = preg_replace('/-\d+[Xx]\d+\./', ".", $html);```  and my images were not blurry anymore plus the ```150x150``` surfix was also removed.